# Using JQuery to let the user drag and drop text into a specific DIV

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

So, basically I'm trying to use the draggable and droppable functions to create this. The javascript for it is like this:

```
$(init);

function init() {
    $('#HeaderDrag').draggable({
        cursor: 'move',
        revert: true,
        containment: '#Content2'
    });

    $('#header').droppable({
        accept: '#HeaderDrag',
        drop: handleDropEvent

    });
}
function handleDropEvent(event, ui) {
    var draggable = ui.draggable;
}
```

the DIVS:

```
    <div id="HeaderDrag"> Header </div>
    <div id = "header">drop me here</div>
```

I can drag the div called "HeaderDrag" but when I try dropping it onto the div "header", it doesn't work and the "HeaderDrag" simply reverts back to its original place. How can I make it work so that it will successfully drop onto the div "header", BUT NOT onto other divs that I might create in the future, only onto the div called "header".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exacly sure what you want to happend but here my attempt:

```
$('#HeaderDrag').draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    revert: true
});

$('#header').droppable({
    accept: '#HeaderDrag',
    drop: handleDropEvent
});

function handleDropEvent(event, ui) {
    $(this).append($('#HeaderDrag'));
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kW3TB/

Comment: Hi, that's similar to what I want, however in your JQuery the "header" div moves up when "HeaderDrag" is moved into it. I want the "header" div to also stay where it is.